# Symfony command / Cron jobs doesn't works with Ovh

Tags: php, symfony, ovh

Here is my problem. I'm developping a Symfony project which acces to telephony and emails data from OVH API. For that, I use cron job (from Ovh board).

I have php files ( **home/mySite/www/command.php**) which contains :

```
<?php
shell_exec("sh mycommand.sh");

 ?>
```

And my bash file ( **home/mySite/mycommand.sh**) :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /homez.mynumber/mysite/www
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony
```

I'm sure that the path is good cause I get error **line 2: cd: /homez.mynumber/mysite/www: No such file or directory**

So I removed line 2 :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony
```

And get error **No such file or directory**

I actually don't know how to make it works. Thanks for yout help !

Comment: Can you please pastebin the whole trace created by `bin/console converseo:updateTelephony -vvv` and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your command? Does it end with "Command" as mentioned in symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Comment: Yes, cause my command works fine with SSH terminal, but not with cron job..